# Trying to use migrations in a project other then the startup project results in error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi I am trying to take advantage of Entity Framework migrations but when I add this command:

> PM> Add-Migration
>
> cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
>
> Supply values for the following parameters:
>
> Name: CodeArtMigration

I get back this error message:

> Cannot determine a valid start-up project. Using project 'CodeArt.DataAccess' instead. Your configuration file and working directory may not be set as expected. Use the -StartUpProjectName parameter to set one explicitly. Use the -Verbose switch for more information.
>   No packages installed.
>   The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'CodeArt.DataAccess'.

The last part of the message that says that Entity Framework is not available in he current project is not true because I do have a reference to Entity Framework.

The package source is set to Microsoft and .NET but I als
My code is structured in 3 layers I wanted to add the migration data in my DataAccess layer.Also I wanted to minimize thereference to Entity Framework only in my data access layer.

Comment: did you check in the Package manager console the dropdownlist where you select the project?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your Package Manager Console has the right project selected in the drop down labeled  "Default project:" to the upper right of Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio.

Here's where to find it in Visual Studio 2015:
[image]

Comment: The right package was selected the problem was that I had no packed.config file with an Entity Framework id

Comment: @aleczandru Can you please clarify how you actually solved this issue? I am having the exact same message.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. I've checked Default project and it was selected appropriately. can someone help on this?

Comment: Having the same issue with VS2017 the correct project is selected